# Shell command in VBA not using the PATH variable (executing .jar from VBA)

Tags: vba, shell, java-8, ms-word, executable-jar

Under Windows 7 (64-bit) and Office 2010 in a Word VBA macro I'm making a `Shell` call to java to execute a .jar file. The code is part of distribution that supposedly works in Office 2007 (which I don't have).

```
ShellCommand = "java -classpath ..."
TaskID = Shell(ShellCommand, ShellWindowState)
```

Anyway, the `Shell` command returns a process ID, but the process terminates immediately with no `Err.Number` I'm not actually able to get much info about why.

However, I suspected it couldn't find the `java` command. I verified that my PATH is correct by opening manually a `CMD.exe` window and running the `ShellCommand` (which I printed using `Debug.Print`). Indeed, my PATH variable is set to point to where the latest JRE is installed, which is also evidenced by typing `java -version` and seeing the proper output.

So, still not trusting `Shell` from VBA, I hardcoded the ShellCommand as follows:

```
ShellCommand = "c:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_72\jre\bin\java -classpath ..."
```

To my (un)suprise, the Shell command works and my .jar was executed as it should.

So, who can tell me why the system `PATH` variable is ignored in `ShellCommand` or, better yet, how I can code my VBA program so that whenever I update my JRE on Windows 7 (`java.exe` is a moving target every couple of weeks it seems), it will find the `java.exe`?

Comment: You might be able to use `Environ("PATH")` to get it. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg264486(v=office.15).aspx

Comment: Thanks @RubberDuck - I checked the PATH value from VBA, and it got me thinking. See the edits. Java 8 runtime seems to have been the culprit. I'm too tired to re-install it (to see if the problem comes back).

Comment: You should add your solution as an answer and accept it if the question is 'closed' :)

Comment: I tend to find using `CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Exec("CMD /C " &  ShellCommand).StdOut.ReadAll` helps for retreiving the output from your shell command. Also, I don't think VBA adds required quotation marks when expanding a variable as CMD does, so if your path contains spaces like "..\Program Files\" you will need to manually add the extra quotes e.g.

`Shell("""" & Environ("PATH") & """" &  ShellCommand, ShellWindowState)`

Hope that makes sense....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### TL;DR: Remove Java 8

The inventory of my Java installs shows some complexity (!)

- Java 7 Update 72
- Java 7 Update 72 (64-bit)
- Java SE Development Kit 7 Update 72 (64-bit)
- Java 8 Update 25

The first part of the `PATH` that I displayed with `Environ("PATH")` shows `C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath` which is a set of `SYMLINK`s as follows:

```
C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath>dir

 Directory of C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath

2014-10-16  10:32    <DIR>          .
2014-10-16  10:32    <DIR>          ..
2014-10-16  10:32    <SYMLINK>      java.exe [C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_25\bin\java.exe]
2014-10-16  10:32    <SYMLINK>      javaw.exe [C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_25\bin\javaw.exe]
2014-10-16  10:32    <SYMLINK>      javaws.exe [C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_25\bin\javaws.exe]
```

As an experiment, I removed Java 8.

That leaves the javapath setting as follows (which is Java 7 64-bit):

```
C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath>dir

 Directory of C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath

2014-10-28  21:14    <DIR>          .
2014-10-28  21:14    <DIR>          ..
2014-10-28  21:14    <SYMLINK>      java.exe [C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\java.exe]
2014-10-28  21:14    <SYMLINK>      javaw.exe [C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\javaw.exe]
2014-10-28  21:14    <SYMLINK>      javaws.exe [C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\javaws.exe]
```

Running my VBA application now works without a hard-coded path to `java.exe`.

*My hypothesis that the PATH variable was being ignored was wrong.*

My new hypothesis is that Java 8 (32-bit) was not working properly when called from `Shell`, since it was executing the .jar file properly within a `cmd.exe` window (with the same path).